# Android install debug APK

Tags: android, installation, apk

So, I've created an app which installs perfectly from the Android Development Studio. However, when I try to install this by downloading the APK from a web page, I get "App not installed". I have successfully installed previous versions of this and other apps from a web page: and the .APK files which I've downloaded previously will still install. I'm running a Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android version 9, kernel version 4.4.111-18920278 from Wed October 7 2020, build number PPR1.180610.011.G950FXXSBDTJ1. Any ideas? TIA, Graeme

Comment: "by downloading the APK from a web page" -- how exactly did you create the APK that you put on the Web server?

Comment: Are you mean you installed the app by Android Studio and now you want to install your released app over it ?

Comment: "by downloading the APK from a web page" - I created the .APK in Intellij (the app-debug apk) and uploaded it to a web server. The APK installs successfully from Intellij, but won't install from the .apk copied to the device.

Comment: "Are you mean you installed the app by Android Studio and now you want to install your released app over it ?" - I can install the app directly from Android Studio (Intellij), but I want to allow a couple of friends to install the app on their devices for testing and commenting purposes: and as they are remote, I can't install it on their devices directly. I have used this means of distribution successfully in the past.